# Google Maps controls look all wrong in Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

so I needed to embed a personalized Google Map into a WP page. I created a template for the page, so that the head section only loads the necessary scripts on the correct page.

That works. The only problem is, some controls look all wrong. Take a look:

http://mercatinobrocantage.com/?page_id=80

The zoom control is small and looks strange. The Street View control is all but invisible. Also, the X to close the dialog popup is wrong two.

I have no idea how to fix this nor have I seen anything of the kind.

Can somebody help me out? Thanks guys.

This is the map-related code I used.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {

        var Brocantage = new google.maps.LatLng(44.049658, 8.21903);
        var Compasso = new google.maps.LatLng(44.049658, 8.21903)

        var myStyle =[
            {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [
                      { visibility: "off" }
                ]
            }
        ];

        var mapOptions = {
                center: Compasso,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                zoom: 17,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                                    position:         google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
                },
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                                    position:     google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
                },
                styles: myStyle
              };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);


        var contentString = 
            '<h5>Mercatino Brocantage</h5>'+
            '<p>Via Carloforte 52<br>' +
            '17031 Albenga (SV)<br>'+
            'Tel. + 39 334 8560445<br>'+
            'E-mail <a         href="mailto:brocantagebazar@gmail.com">brocantagebazar@gmail.com</a>'+
            '</p>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });

        var image = "http://www.mercatinobrocantage.com/images/blue-dot.png";

        var markerOptions = {
                position: Brocantage,
                map: map,
                title: 'Mercatino Brocantage',
                draggable: false,
                icon: image,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            };      
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });


        };
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style>
    #map {width: 100%; height: 600px;}
</style>
```

Comment: looking at the console it looks like you've got a few 404's to clean up.  maybe that will help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it just after asking the question. Firebug helped me find a css conflict involving the img selector. I had to add this to the code:

```
#map img {max-width:none;}
```

and now it's fine.